# mono, unix sockets

Tags: c#, mono, named-pipes

Does anyone know an example of c# (mono) application that creates unix domain socket and listens to it async way?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same code as a .Net example? You might want to start by looking for any c# example as it should be appropriate.

Comment: not exactly, i want to use Mono.Unix namespace which is unavailable in .NET

Comment: I'm guessing there's something specific you need from the Mono.Unix sockets implementation that's not available in the System.Net.Sockets. Just out of curiosity, what is it? I can't help but am curious.

Comment: @Lazarus: It's just using a UnixEndPoint instead of an IPEndPoint

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the method GracefulShutdown() in [ModMonoWebSource.cs](https://github.com/mono/xsp/blob/master/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/ModMonoWebSource.cs). After the point where the socket is created, it does not matter any more whether it was a unix domain socket or an IPv4 socket. Accepting connection asynchronously is done in Mono.WebServer/ folder, but I'll let you find out where and how.

Answer (score 0):

May be it approach for this question.

```
       var listeningPort = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unix, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        var endPoint = new UnixDomainSocketEndPoint(path);

        listeningPort.Bind(endPoint);

        listeningPort.Listen(0);

        while (true)
        {

            var socket = await listeningPort.AcceptAsync();

            var result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(transferBuffer, CancellationToken.None);
            //...
        }
```